# Unable to declare a function in the parent class in PHP

Tags: php

I am unable to debug the code:

```
<?php
    echo "hello <br>";

    class gang {
        public function __construct() {
            echo "parent constructor call <br>";
        }

        public fetchOperators() {
            echo "fetchOperators accessed <br>";
        }
    }

    class bang {
        private $operators;

        public function __construct() {
            echo "constructor call <br>";
        }
    };

    $ob = new bang();
    $ob2 = new gang();
    $ob->fetchOperators();
?>
```

I am getting HTTP Error 500. Removing the function fetchOperators works and I am able to create the instances ob and ob2.

However, upon adding the public function fetchOperators and accessing it using ob generates the error 500.

Comment: you have not extended the class?? try `class bang extends gang{`

Comment: you missed the 'function' keyword

Comment: Missing keyword.

Comment: `;` after second class also wrong

Comment: `fetchOperators` is in `$ob2` not in `$ob`

Comment: Sorry, rookie mistake.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add **function** before defining like as, and also i have seen that you forgot to add extend while inheriting parent class method

```
 public function fetchOperators() {
        echo "fetchOperators accessed <br>";
    }
```

**Please check updated code**,

```
<?php

echo "hello <br>";

class gang {

    public function __construct() {
        echo "parent constructor call <br>";
        }

        public function fetchOperators() {
        echo "fetchOperators accessed <br>";
    }

}

class bang extends gang {

    private $operators;

    public function __construct() {
        echo "constructor call <br>";
    }

}

$ob = new bang();
$ob2 = new gang();
$ob->fetchOperators();
```

Comment: Sorry, rookie mistake.
Thanks :)

Comment: @AviralSrivastava, please check updated hope it will help you thanks